# One Word vs. Multi Word YouTube Channel Name

Tags: youtube, production

I'm getting ready to create a **channel name** with three short words. I'm trying to decide if it would be better to **mash** them together into **one word** or **keep separate words**. Searches for the subject only find people talking about how to create a one word channel, not why. I noticed that the trending and recommended videos on the front page are a mix of mashed together words and multi word names. Any advice on which would be better and why is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: That's not a video question. A channel name is like finding a title for your œuvre. The question may fit better to https://writing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Looking at Writing SE posts, I don't think it would be welcome there. I noticed these posts here: [Monetizing...](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/12870/monetizing-youtube-channel-with-videos-containing-cc-licensed-content?rq=1), [Starting...](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29767/starting-a-youtube-channel-advise-questions-tips?rq=1) and [Will a Youtube...](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/30583/will-a-youtube-video-with-clips-from-a-copyright-protected-anime-website-animei) and thought this might be the right place.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it really matters. People do both all the time. It really all just comes down to the content you provide, using appropriate tags on each video, and being consistent with your postings.

Answer (score 0):

If you mush all three words together, it will make the name harder to understand. On the other hand, having all three words as one word may make the name more recognizable, if the name you chose is a common phrase. If your name is three words, when people look it up, they may find videos about that topic listed above your channel. This would limit your early exposure, as people looking for videos about Video Editing Explained (or whatever your channel will be called) would probably find videos about that listed above your channel. I light of that, putting your three words together as one word would probably be better.